# I want to use a variable in other files but global variables is not recommended in c#, is there another way of it?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to use var drainx and have other files access it

I've read global variables in c# not good, looking for another way for other files to get access to it without making it global. or can i make this method public void ItemSelected(object sender, System.EventArgs e).  but then i dont want the switch statements that comes with it, i only need the variable when the user selects a number.

```
//this is fired when user changes or selects new selection
void ItemSelected(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //to get value user selected
    var drainx = drain.Items[drain.SelectedIndex];

    switch (drainx)
    {
        case "1":
            DisplayAlert(drainx, "selected Value", "OK");
            drainPicker1();
            drain2Picker.IsVisible = false;
            drain3Picker.IsVisible = false;
            drain4Picker.IsVisible = false;
        break;
        case "2":
            DisplayAlert(drainx, "selected Value", "OK");
            drain1Picker.IsVisible = true;
            drain2Picker.IsVisible = true;
            drain3Picker.IsVisible = false;
            drain4Picker.IsVisible = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: making it public

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public static string item;
```

I want the this class on another file to get access to it but "item" is  error- the item does not exist in it's current context

```
public AddNewDataPage()
{    
InitializeComponent();
switch (item)
{
```

UPDATE: below now it works. i can see variable but i like to use the value in it too. ANY IDEAS?

```
switch (MainPage.item)
{
case "1":
DisplayAlert(MainPage.item, "selected Value", "OK");
break;
```

Comment: So did i understand right, you want only the variable drainx to be global? If so then define this variable outside of the method as a public property.

Comment: There´s no **global** in C#. The closest thing is just a `public static` member. Having said this you can of course make your `drain` a `public` member of your class - either `static` or not, depending on if `drain` reflects a specific **instance** of your class or not. You should provide where you want to access the variable, so we get a better image of what you need.

Comment: HimBromBeere - i want another file to access it and use switch statements like the one above but will display label and entry instead of picker.

Comment: `I want to ... have other files access it`  Start thinking in terms of classes not files

Comment: _"the item does not exist in it's current context"_ -- outside the class where they are declared, you need to refer to static members using the name of the class: e.g. `switch (MainPage.item)`.

Comment: MainPage.item works.  but how do i get the value it held?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to declare variable outside of your method with `public static` access modifier. With this you can access it's value from other file with `ClassName.variableName` syntax.

There is no Global variables in C# (in the sense that they don't belong to any class) closest you can get is using `public` access modifier.

And `"I've read global variables in c# not good"` this statement isn't right, there are many reasons for public modifier(closest to global variable in C#) in c#, that's why it exists, good or not depends on how you use it.

Comment: so i added    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static string item;

Comment: Declaring something `public` doesn't make it a global variable. I think you're mixing up your terms.

Comment: @Enigmativity I didn't say that it makes, i just said that with that he can access it from other classes

Comment: @PrOdiGy - You need to explain that better. There's no mention of how you can access from "wherever you want". In your third paragraph you continue to be confusing in suggesting that the `public` modifier has something to do with global variables.

Comment: @Enigmativity I got your point, will be more precise next time :)

Public/public static is as close as you can get to global, in c# we don't have globals, as i said, so that's why when I talked about globals being good or not i used public in my third paragraph. But again I admit i sounded a bit confusing maybe

Comment: @PrOdiGy - Would you please fix the answer?